# Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a new theme using **SXA CLI.**

```
? Enter your login sitecore\admin
? Enter your password [hidden]
? Specify theme path. Root is Themes folder(format <RootFolderName/ChildFolderName>) Test Tenant\SiteTest
? Do you want to set up theme config file? yes
C:\Users\samed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sxa\CLI\util\serverRequests.js:25
                    _c8a‍.g.console.log(chalk.bold.red(body.match(/<li>([\d\w\s\.]*)<\/li>/)[1]))

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
```

I was searching on the Google, and there is some post about adding the **user role** to the **sitecore\admin**, and the name of the role is **sitecore\PowerShell Extensions Remoting**

Is that a fix, or there is something else that can be done

Comment: Edit your question and paste error in a text snippet instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two potential causes for this error:

1. The situation you described - the user you are logging in with must have the`sitecore\PowerShell Extensions Remoting` role, not just the `Administrator` checkbox.  Reference: https://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2021/03/sitecore-sxa-cli-theme-setup-error.html?m=1
2. The user must also have a simple (assume alphanumeric only) password.  A password containing `#` did not get encoded correctly, causing the login attempt to fail.

Note that the main Sitecore log file will likely contain additional information about this error. e.g.

```
8548 22:48:35 WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2Fsitecore%2520modules%2FPowerShell%2FServices%2FRemoteScriptCall.ashx
```